# Return a Value from Column B if the search Value is found in any Column through Z-AG

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is the scenario that I have been trying to puzzle out.

In Sheet1 Column B, I have a list of SKUs, in Sheet2 Columns Y-AG I have multiple lists of SKUs that could match what is in Sheet1 Column B.

I'm trying to return the value of Sheet2 Column B if any of the values in Sheet2 Columns Y-AG match Sheet 1 Column B.

I've tried the following formula, but alas it returns only errors.

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$B:$B,MATCH($C2,'Sheet2'!Y:AG,0),1)
```

Thank you for your help kind people!

Comment: Would the us of a helper column be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Combination of MMULT (Matrix Multiplication) & INDEX, MATCH finds value from multiple columns.*

[image]

[image]

---

**N.B.**

The used formula finds Name, **Sanjay** in cell `A67`, in `Sheet 1 A65:A72`,  matched with Name, **Sanjay** in `B39`, in `Sheet 2 B37:D44`, and returns value **Kim** from `Sheet 2 Column A (A37:A44)`, in `Sheet 1 Column B in Cell B67`.

- An array (CSE) formula, in Sheet 1 cell `B65`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$37:$A$44,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(Sheet2!$B$37:$D$44=Sheet1!A65),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Sheet2!$B$37:$D$44)^0)),0)),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.

*Adjust cell Sheet name & cell references in the formula as needed.*

---

**How the formula works:**

- `(Sheet2!$B$37:$D$44=Sheet1!A65)`, works inside out, where `Sheet1!A65` works as criteria, finds name in Sheet 2 `B37:D44`, generates  `TRUE/FALSE` for every value in `B37:D44`.
- The `COLUMN` function creates 2nd numeric array, has dimension of 3 col X 1 row .
- `TRANSPOSE` converts this array to 1 col X 3 rows.
- The power of zero simply converts all numbers in the array to 1.
- The `MMULT` function is then used to perform matrix multiplication.
- `IFERROR`, as usual handle `"N/A"` error.

Comment: Glad to help you @Preston ,, keep asking ☺